# How do I circumvent OpenDNS content blocking? Is it a hardware or software issue?

Tags: blocking, opendns

I know something like this has been posted before, but I tried out all the solutions discussed in the article and none of them worked. I'm beginning to think it is a hardware problem, stemming from how my router is configured, because I've tried numerous public and unblocked DNS's like Google's and 4.2.2.2 and my previous ISP's but to no avail. After changing the DNS server used, I restart the computer, and still nothing changes. It may be helpful to mention that I am using a Linux computer(Ubuntu to be exact).

Is the MAC address the problem? Or could it be the hardware configuration?

My current settings are as follows:

MAC Address: 00:11:D8:EE:1B:C5
MTU:automatic

IP4V settings:
         Method: Automatic(DHCP) adresses only
         DNS servers: 4.2.2.2

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If OpenDNS is blocking websites, then somewhere down the line, OpenDNS has been configured as your DNS server (somewhere down the line). Most of the time, this would be set on your local computer, but it could also be established as the DNS server of your router (but this would only be used if you are using DHCP or you have set your router as the DNS server). Your ISP might also be using OpenDNS, but I highly doubt this.

To check to see if you are actually using OpenDNS, just check out [welcome.opendns.com](http://welcome.opendns.com), which will tell you quite clearly if you are actually using OpenDNS or not.

If it reports that you are not using OpenDNS, then you should flush your DNS cache. This should alleviate the problem

Comment: It says that I am using OpenDNS, so does that mean that my router is using OpenDNS? If so, what should I do?

Comment: You would have to log onto your router and change the settings. Check your router's documentation on how to do that...

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I needed! Enjoy your rep, that I'm not sure how to give to you.